# Raspberry PiとCO2センサーのGNDを繋いだ際に電源が落ちてしまう現象

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, センサー

Raspberry初心者です。
CO2センサーの[MH-Z19](http://clima-sensor.ru/files/MH-Z19_Manual_V2.pdf)と[ラズパイ3モデルB](https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B01CHJRAL8/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)をオスメスで繋ごうとしています。
ただ、ラズパイGPIOの6番GNDとセンサー側のGND（7番）をつなぐと、ラズパイの電源が落ちてしまいます。
ラズパイ側のGPIOにはジャンパーワイヤを繋ぎ、センサーには繋がない場合には電源は落ちません。
原因・対策として何が考えられるでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

電源や信号は接続せずに、GNDのみを接続するだけで電源が落ちるという事でしょうか。

そうであればMH-Z19には問題はなく、ラズパイのGNDと思っている箇所がGNDではないと考えられます。
電源が落ちる理由は
①電源の供給能力がオーバーするか、
②ラズパイのリセット端子がONとなるか、
③電源のイネーブル端子がOffとなる位しかないと思います。

まずはあなたがGPIO6番と考えておられる端子が本当にGNDかを把握するため、
テスターでGND端子との抵抗値を測定してみてください。
すでに確認済であれば、
ラズパイには複数のGND端子があるので、他の端子で同様の現象が発生するか
確認して頂ければと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認し、試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

MH-Z19 の GND と Vin は隣接していたと思いますがこれがピンのハンダ不良などでショートしているということはないでしょうか？　確認してみてください。